# Find file and add lines ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

How can I find a given file and then add a few lines to the end of it? Right now I have something like

```yaml
---
- name: Ansible find file and add some lines
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: find file
      find:
        paths: /etc
        patterns: 'somefile.conf'
```

Ansible found that file. What's next?

Comment: Why do you want to find a file when you already have the path? Simply use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html). If you have a problem [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Comment: This playbook will have to go through a lot of servers, I don't know if the path will look like "/etc/thisFile" on each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the file

```sh
shell> cat etc/somefile.conf
line1
line2
```

Register the result of the *find* module and select the paths

```yaml
- name: Ansible find file and add some lines
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: find file
      find:
        paths: etc
        patterns: 'somefile.conf'
      register: result
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

gives the list of the files (there might be more of them)

```yaml
  msg:
  - etc/somefile.conf
```

Use *lineinfile* to  add the line

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        line: "last line"
        insertafter: EOF
      loop: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat etc/somefile.conf
line1
line2
last line
```

---

The next option is *blockinfile*. e.g.

```yaml
    - blockinfile:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        block: |
          last line -2
          last line -1
          last line
        insertafter: EOF
      loop: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat etc/somefile.conf
line1
line2
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
last line -2
last line -1
last line
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```